# Cannot call algorithm2e procedure relax()

Tags: captions, algorithms, algorithm2e

I want to write a procedure called *relax* using the package `algorithm2e`. I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{procedure}
This procedure does something\;
\caption{relax()}
\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```

This gives the error

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
```

If I write

```
\caption{test()}
```

instead, everything works fine. I thought that maybe the macro `relax` would overwrite the LaTeX command of the same name, so I tried the option *nokwfunc* to prevent that from happening, without success. How can I give my procedure the name *relax*?

Comment: `\relax` is a protected TeX command. Maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: **Please report this, maybe it is a bug.** According to the manual, you can use **algorithm2esty-discussion@lirmm.fr** for discussions about the package.

Comment: Sent a bugreport. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{procedure}
This procedure does something\;
\caption{r{}elax()}
\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```